# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting the error in GetTotalMaterialCost I have already checked the whole thing. I even remove excess con.Close but the error will still prompt t it.

---

```
decimal GetTotalMaterialCost()
{
    decimal total = 0;
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText =
        "SELECT SUM(rm.Quantity * m.SellingPrice) AS TotalMaterialCost FROM Resource_Materials rm " +
        "JOIN Materials m ON m.MaterialID = rm.MaterialID " +
        "JOIN ProjectTasks t ON t.TaskID = rm.TaskID " +
        "WHERE t.TaskID=@TaskID HAVING COUNT (*) > 0";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
    object data = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (data == null)
        total = 0;
    else
        total = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    return total;
}
```

---

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ProjectTasks SET Name=@Name, Description=@Description " +
        "WHERE TaskID=@TaskID; " +
        "SELECT TOP 1 TaskID FROM ProjectTasks ORDER BY TaskID DESC;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Resource_Materials SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Equipments SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Vehicles SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Contractors SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Projects SET ActualCost=@ActualCost WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActualCost", GetAmount());
    con.Close();

    Helper.AddLog("1", "Add", "Assigned Resources to Task");
    Response.Redirect("~/Projects/Default.aspx");
}
```

---

[Here is the link for my whole code as reference](http://pastie.org/private/3swdpirzytdol8m4l55q)

---

The said error is at line 679

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens because you use a global connection object and somewhere in your code the connection was not properly closed. For example, an exception is triggered somewhere in your code and you forget to close the connection in that case.

The resolution is always the same.
**Do not keep a global connection object.

Create it when you need it and destroy it with the appropriate syntax.**

[There is connection pooling infrastructure in ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) that has been devised just to give better performance when you are in a `create/open/use/close` scenario.

```
decimal GetTotalMaterialCost()
{
    decimal total = 0;
    string query = @"SELECT SUM(rm.Quantity * m.SellingPrice) AS TotalMaterialCost 
                    FROM Resource_Materials rm 
                    JOIN Materials m ON m.MaterialID = rm.MaterialID 
                    JOIN ProjectTasks t ON t.TaskID = rm.TaskID
                    WHERE t.TaskID=@TaskID HAVING COUNT (*) > 0";

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....constringhere...)
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        .....
     }
    return total;
}
```

In this way the connection object is local and the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) ensures that is closed and disposed at the closing brace even if you hit some kind of exception.

Of course this pattern should be applied in every point where you try to reach your database and the global connection object should be removed. The only thing that could be kept global is the connection string and also for this there is a better place to store it (IE. The app.config ConnectionString section)

Said that it is a possibility that you have an error caused by the AddWithValue usage. This method defines the DataType of the parameter looking at the value passed. It seems that your TaskID field is an integer, but you prepare a parameter with AddWithValue and pass a string. So the query will use a parameter with the wrong datatype. 
I suggest to use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
       Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString()));
```

Finally, just give a cursory glance to your code, I suggest to change the methods called by your Page_Load to receive a connection object opened directly in the Page_Load event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....constringhere...)
    {
        GetProjectMaterials(con);
        GetProjectEquipments(con);
        GetProjectVehicle(con);
        GetProjectContractors(con);
        GetTasks(con,resourceID);
        GetMaterials(con);
        GetEquipments(con);
        GetVehicles(con);
        GetLContractors(con);
    }
}
```

Of course you need to change also the other methods that calls these methods to pass a connection, but if I am not wrong, you already have to build a connection in those callers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use local variable for connection together with "using" since .NET SQL provider will do connection pooling for you and "using" will ensure that your connection is properly closed and disposed. So your code will look like:

```
    decimal GetTotalMaterialCost()
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(/*connection string if not configured via web.config*/))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "SELECT SUM(rm.Quantity * m.SellingPrice) AS TotalMaterialCost FROM Resource_Materials rm " +
                    "JOIN Materials m ON m.MaterialID = rm.MaterialID " +
                    "JOIN ProjectTasks t ON t.TaskID = rm.TaskID " +
                    "WHERE t.TaskID=@TaskID HAVING COUNT (*) > 0";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
                object data = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (data == null)
                    total = 0;
                else
                    total = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` twice without resetting it. Your line setting the `total` variable should be `total = (decimal) data;`. After all, you already have the answer, why not just use it instead of re-executing the code?